# Getting points along a XAML Shapes.Path

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, vector-graphics

I'm trying to get points along a Shapes.Path object from a Silverlight MainWindow.xaml file. I use Expression Blend to create the path.

The following code works fine unless I try to move the path in expression blend, which only moves the margins. Apparently that doesn't get calculated in, and I get the points from where the path was originally created.

```
        var pathGeometry = path.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
        var currentPoint = new System.Windows.Point();
        var tangentPoint = new System.Windows.Point();
        var rList = new List<Point>();
        var pointsCount = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++)
        {                
            double fraction = (double)i / (double)(pointsCount - 1);

            pathGeometry.GetPointAtFractionLength(fraction, out currentPoint, out tangentPoint);

            rList.Add(currentPoint);
        }
        return rList;
```

Any suggestions on how to get the margin change to also calculate in?

Comment: Can you not just add or subtract the margin?

Answer (score 3):

Ah... I think I see the problem. [PathGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry) does not inherit from UIElement, meaning that it does not have any sense of Margins. The Geometry is hosted within a control that does, and it is that control which actually draws the Geometry onto the screen. If you want to translate a point on the Geometry into screen coordinates, then you'll need to find the location of the host control and calculate the offset.

My guess is that your PathGeometry is hosted inside a [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path) control. (Confusing, no?) Getting the location in screen coordinates is relatively easy. You can call the [PointToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen) method on Path and feed it the calculated point (perhaps adding any padding you may be applying). Getting a point relative to the window is more complicated. You could call PointToScreen (for point 0,0) on the window and then subtract the Path's point from the window's. Or, you could put the Path inside a Canvas (where the Canvas is directly inside the window) and simply get the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left.

You don't say what your ultimate goal is, so it is difficult to recommend a particular solution for you.

Comment: Thanks, you've given me some useful ideas to try.

Comment: Okay, so PointToScreen apparently doesn't work when just importing the XAML into a class, because it's designed to include the position of the window. I need to get the points relative to the position of the grid that the path is inside of. I'm thinking maybe I'll need to find the edges of my path, and then try to calculate a translation based on the difference between that and the margins from the edges of the grid.

Comment: @zmarks22 - You still haven't explained your ultimate goal with this project, but I'm catching hints that you might be trying to shoehorn WPF into completing tasks it was not designed for. There are some graphing assemblies available for .NET. Have you considered those? Here's one I found via codeplex: http://graphlib.codeplex.com/

Comment: It's definitely a hack. I'm trying to use Expression Blend to create lines, and then use the xaml to generate points which are sent using JSON to be rendered by a javascript library to render dots on the screen.